# How do you add delivery time restrictions to WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am new to using Wordpress and the commerce plugins associated with it. I have been trying to setup WooCommerce for a restaurant's online ordering system. I noticed that there seems to be no way to restrict delivery times as being a restaurant they will need to stop accepting orders at a particular time and then continue to accept orders at a particular time the next day.

I feel like there is a simple solution but I just can't seem to find it. Is there another plugin or am I missing a way to set it up properly?

Comment: As StackOverFlow is a coding forum. Asking about plugins is off-topic… But is completely possible with some code to set a delivery time… You will have to search a bit to get started with some code. Then you will be able to update this question if needed to get helped around your code, giving here more details about what you are trying to do…

Comment: No is no such plugin available till now, but as Loic have pointed out, It could be done with the help of a bit coding. But before we start putting effort there, please show us what have you tried (code).